# Laravel Production, CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: php, laravel, http, heroku, cors

After deploying my Laravel API app on Heroku it seems to be having issues with Cors. This was no issue in development, and I can still use the deployed app on postman, but not through regular HTTP requests on my Angular app.

[image]

My Cors.php is the has not been modified

```
   'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

And my Kernel.php uses the HandleCors class

```
 protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Not sure if my angular app needs further changes, since it's working on postman, the call looks like this

```
  // User registration
  register(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('https://secure-fortress-48055.herokuapp.com/api/register', user);
  }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please post everything as text, not as images, to help people help you.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?
I am currently facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

modifie this in your `Cors.php` file .

```
'paths' => ['api/getList', 'api/getDetails/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you post your .env file?
I think you need to modify your .env file and change the following code

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL=https://secure-fortress-48055.herokuapp.com/
```

also you need to change Cors.php

```
    'exposed_headers' => [],
```

to

```
    'exposed_headers' => ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'],
```

Maybe this will help you

Comment: APP_URL was already set, but changing exposed_headers did nothing to help 
I have tried changing a bit in the cors.php, to write out the header names instead of using wildcard and writing out the specific origin of my angular app

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/239#issuecomment-642527759

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by adding headers inside of the api.php routes

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it's one.